# adding a warning message to jpackage installer [SOLVED]

Tags: java, windows-installer, jpackage

Is there a way to display a warning message to .msi file created by jpackage?
If user confirms the warning message of the installation, it will continue otherwise it will exit.

I didn't find any option for jpackage, do you know anything doing it for free?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I managed to do it..
first create some custom resource directory for WIX installer
then find and copy "InstallDirNotEmptyDlg.wxs" file in here
Edit the file like :

[image]

then in jpackage command pass an additional parameter --resource-dir "C:\Projects\wixResource" --verbose

verbose is only to see the process in detail..

then during the installation , if the target path exists
here we pop up this message

Comment: Nice job finding a solution! But note it would be better to have the content of the file in the answer _as text_ formatted as code. See [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/6395627) for more information.